# What lines should be commented out in my sources.list file?

Tags: apt, updates, security

I have just updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 last weekend. I haven't downloaded any extra programs as of yet. I checked my sources.list file and it has the following lines in it:

```
deb http:"//gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http:"//security.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http:"//archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

I am concerned that the security line is commented out. I know it is an old version, but I'd like to know whether there should be a newer version of this line that isn't commented out?

Answer (score 1):

Anything related to older release can be removed from the sources.list.

During an upgrade the older release will get commented out (by adding a "#").

> but I'd like to know whether there should be a newer version of this line that isn't commented out?

That depends on what is checked in software&updates. If security is unchecked there does not need to be an extra line (though I would expect it to be there but commented out).

Comment: thanks for that. I have just gone into the software and update section and for some reason in the other software tab, and the updates tab, the important security updates box and the recommended updates box were not checked. I have also checked these boxes in the update tab as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example /etc/apt/sources.list file I just snagged out of a spare version of trusty. I went ahead and put the security updates at the top, removed the comments and "deb-src" entries as well.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse


deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
```

---

Alternatively, you could just edit your current list to look like this instead:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After I apply the updates (via sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install) Ill see if the list matches yours.

Comment: I've included more info at the end.

Comment: After checking boxes in software update, and checking the sources.list file again, I noticed that the two raring updates had been uncommented. I recommented them and checked the software and updates section, and the two boxes that I checked in the "Other software" tab have now been unchecked again.

Comment: @JohnSmith Just leave those lines uncommented and then run the command as suggested by Avinash Raj to change the word raring to trusty and you'll be good to go.

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/raring/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` It would change all the raring string to trusty. So it's better to do a backup before editing the sources.list file. `sudo sed -i.bak 's/raring/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Guys thank you very much! I dont have network access at the moment, but I will try the fixes later!

Comment: So it was the updates tab that needed the checkboxes, which had the same affect as mchid's answer as well. They all worked, so thanks for everything!